# JButton's border don't go away even when set the Border to EmptyBorder

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, imageicon

I am designing a GUI using Eclipse on Mac, and I want to make the `JButton` to display only the Icon I set. It looks fine on Mac OS, but when I export it to a jar file, and rut in on Windows OS, the `JButton` looks like this:

[image]

The borders are all `EmptyBorder`.

What did I do wrong? How can I make the square at the back go away?

Comment: Sounds like a L&F issue. And possibly the two operating systems have a different interpretation of transparent pixels in the file format you're using (although that seems unlikely to me). What file format are you using? Also, if you can make a [scce](http://sscce.org/), it might prove helpful.

Comment: @Xiaofan Wu just ensure us those state for JButton is from Windows or from MAC OS

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer this question correctly, an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) will most likely be required. Anyway, I believe that you'll want to invoke [`setContentAreaFilled(false)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setContentAreaFilled%28boolean%29) on your `JButton` instances. That should effectively remove the "square".

However, it is important to note that the exact behavior of calling this function varies on a component-by-component and L&F-by-L&F basis.

---

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public final class JButtonDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();             
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI(){
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JIconButton());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static final class JIconButton extends JButton{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7274140930080397481L;

        public JIconButton(){
            super(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"));
            setContentAreaFilled(false);
            setFocusPainted(false);
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Works on `com.apple.laf.AquaLookAndFeel`, but the armed & pressed UI hints disappear; for fun, try adding `this.setPressedIcon(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon"))`.

Comment: @mre: setContentAreaFilled(false) works! but I didn't write my own JButton class, I just did like okButton.setContentAreaFilled(false); and so on. It works!

Answer (score 2):

1) can't to reproduce that, too hard to say without seeing code that you wrote for that,

2) because you touched XxxButtonUI, and this is really Native OS rellated issue, which Look and Feel is there used for that

3) what happens if you override MetalButtonUI?

4) is there [transulcent](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/) background, or with some Color, or ...